# Notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, mobile-application

I am trying to create an android application which allows users to receive updates from a particular server/website.

For example, whenever I have a piece of information I want to share, like an update or notice, I will post it on this website. Whenever, there are updates posted by me, I want the phone to receive a notification about it as well and add the information into the app.

Just like the gmail app on android. Update immediately when there is a mail and not have a timer to check at every interval.

Does anyone know how can I go about it? I am new to programming, it will be good if your answers in steps for me to follow. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The android application will have a login page which is define the type of the user. Only the updates and information regarding the type of the user will be pushed.

However users of this application, may not login with a google account.

Answer (score 1):

You could use C2DM - Cloud 2 Device Messaging. It's relatively new tech though so not a lot of resources about it.

Here's a good tutorial on it: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

**Edit:** PS: and it's in beta too so might work best as a proof of concept more than an actual product.

Comment: i have made some additions to the question, maybe you can help me with that?